# Is it possible to change an Azure organisational account administrator?

Tags: azure, accounts

My (small) company has an Azure account we use for various projects. Does anyone know if it's possible to change the Account Administrator?

I've figured out how to add technical users as 'Co-Administrators' for subscriptions so they can control services, and even change the Service Administrator, but want to hand over the Account Admin stuff to my operations manager to take care of the boring stuff like billing.

Can't find anything on website or Googling. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried opening a Billing support ticket?

Comment: Yes, and now got a response - see answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raised a Billing Support question through the portal and got a telephone response.

The basic answer is 'yes'. MS can transfer the Account Administration to another user. However, more useful in my case was that they were able to set up a delegate user to allow more than one person to access the billing information.

Doesn't look like there's a UI to do it though.